# How to assign new array in useState variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

My code is given below:

**App.js**

```
const [routes, setRoutes] = useState([]);
const location = useLocation();

const pathnames = location.pathname.split("/");
const newNames = pathnames.map((name) =>
  name.replace("-", " ").toLocaleUpperCase()
);
const BreadCrumbs = newNames.filter((name) => name !== "");

useEffect(() => {
  const createRoute = () => {
    setRoutes(BreadCrumbs);
  };
  createRoute();
}, [BreadCrumbs]);
```

When the path is `"home/all-activities/blogs"`, then `routes=["HOME", "ALL ACTIVITIES", "BLOGS"]`.

The problem is app.js is rendering infinite times despite updating the state only once with `useEffect` hook. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

TL:DR
Use `useMemo`. It will stop the infinite renders.

The problem is you are changing state with `setRoutes`, causing the component to re-render. When it re-renders, `const BreadCrumbs` is assigned a new value. This triggers `useEffect` again, and the whole thing starts over again, an infinite amount of times.

Try using `useMemo` on `const BreadCrumbs`.

Example:

```
const BreadCrumbs = useMemo(() => {
  return *some array*
}, [*dependencies go here*])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no so much informations, so check this :

1. Does your app contain a BrowserRouter ? https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router
2. Your dependencies array is wrong. The source of truth is "pathnames"
3. maybe you can initialize the "route" state in a useEffect callback, you probably don't need a useEffect like this
   `const [counter, setCounter] = useState(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 16));`

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

This issue here is that you've used a dependency for the `useEffect` hook that changes each render cycle, and since the `useEffect` hook enqueues a state update it triggers the component to rerender. This creates the render looping you are seeing.

```
const [routes, setRoutes] = useState([]);

const location = useLocation(); // <-- declared each render cycle
const pathnames = location.pathname.split("/"); // <-- declared each render cycle
const newNames = pathnames.map((name) => // <-- declared each render cycle
  name.replace("-", " ").toLocaleUpperCase()
);
const BreadCrumbs = newNames.filter((name) => name !== ""); // <-- declared each render cycle
useEffect(() => {
  const createRoute = () => {
    setRoutes(BreadCrumbs);
  };
  createRoute();
}, [BreadCrumbs]); // <-- dependency changes each render cycle
```

## Solution

It's actually an anti-pattern in React to store derived "state" into local component state. The `routes` value is derived from the current `location.pathname` value. Just compute the `routes` value directly from `location.pathname`.

Example:

```
const { pathname } = useLocation();

const routes = pathname
  .slice(1)   // <-- remove leading "/" character
  .split("/") // <-- convert path to array of path segments
  .map(name => name.replace("-", " ").toLocaleUpperCase());
```

```js
const pathname = "/home/all-activities/blogs";

const routes = pathname
  .slice(1) // <-- remove leading "/" character
  .split("/") // <-- convert path to array of path segments
  .map(name => name.replace("-", " ").toLocaleUpperCase());

console.log(routes); // ["HOME", "ALL ACTIVITIES", "BLOGS"]
```

`routes` will be recomputed each time the component renders, but this won't trigger a rerender. If for some reason there's any performance issue you can always memoize the `routes` value. In fact, just about any time you have some derived "state" and you initially implement a `useState`/`useEffect` pair you should reconsider and instead use the `useMemo` hook instead.

Example:

```
const { pathname } = useLocation();

const routes = useMemo(() => pathname
  .slice(1)
  .split("/")
  .map(name => name.replace("-", " ").toLocaleUpperCase()),
  [pathname]
);
```

Now `routes` is a stable reference and only recomputed if the `pathname` string value changes.